# Could not upload xml file to FTP Server

Tags: php, laravel, ftp-server

I'm trying to put an xml file in an FTP Server using php and laravel.

I could not upload the file to the Server.

Here is my php code

```
    $fileName = 'test.xml';
    $filePath = public_path($fileName);
    $conn_id = ftp_connect(env('FTP_HOST'));
    ftp_login($conn_id, env('FTP_USERNAME'), env('FTP_PASSWORD'));
    ftp_put($conn_id, '/files/test/', $filePath, FTP_ASCII);
```

But it is showing error as

```
    ERROR:
    ftp_put(): Could not create file.
```

I have tried in Laravel also

```
     $fileName = 'test.xml';
     \Storage::disk('ftp')->put($fileName, fopen(public_path($fileName), 'r+'));
```

I have configured the driver in filesystems

```
'ftp' => [
    'driver' => 'ftp',
    'host' => '12.12.12.12', 
    'username' => `user`,
    'password' => 'password',

],
```

Expected : Need to put the xml file in ftp server which is in project public path.

Comment: It may be because of the server's root directory is different from the FTP root directory